# Expected value of conditional on random pair

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Let X and Y be the Random variables that describe pressure on car
> wheels (X refers to the front wheel, Y refers to the back wheel). They
> follow a probability distribution according to the table:

| X/Y | 10 | 12 | 14 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | .1229 | .0875 | .1229 |
| 14 | .1229 | .1229 | .0875 |
| 15 | .0875 | .1229 | .1229 |

> What is the expected value of $X - Y$ conditional at $X = 13$?

My guess is to do $$P(X = 13) = P(X = 10, Y = 10) + P(X = 10, Y = 12) + P(X = 10, Y = 14)$$ and then I have $$P(Y = y \,|\, X = 13) = \frac{P(X = 13, Y = y)}{P(X = 13)}~.$$

But from now how do I get to the expected value of $Y | X = 13$?

Comment: So you work out $P(Y = 10 \mid X = 13),P(Y = 12 \mid X = 13),P(Y = 14 \mid X = 13)$ and then $E[Y \mid X=13] $ $=10P(Y = 10 \mid X = 13)+12P(Y = 12 \mid X = 13)+14P(Y = 14 \mid X = 13)$

Comment: $\mathbb E(Y=y|X=13)=\sum\limits_{y \in \{10,12,14\}}  y\cdot \frac{P(X = 13, Y = y)}{P(X = 13)}$

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in a comment you can compute $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=13)$ by iterating over all the possible values for Y and multiplying by the probability of each occurring given $X=13$

$$\mathbb{E}(X|Y=13) = 10\mathbb{P}(Y=10∣X=13)+12\mathbb{P}(Y=12∣X=13)+14\mathbb{P}(Y=14∣X=13) $$

To get $\mathbb{P}(Y=10∣X=13)$, for example, we can use
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y=10∣X=13)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y=10,X=13)}{\mathbb{P}(X=13)}\\
&=\frac{0.1229}{0.1229 + 0.0875 + 0.1229}\\
&=0.5372
\end{align*}

Doing similar for $\mathbb{P}(Y=12∣X=13)$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y=14∣X=13)$ and plugging into the first equation will give us
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X|Y=13) &= 10\mathbb{P}(Y=10∣X=13)+12\mathbb{P}(Y=12∣X=13)+14\mathbb{P}(Y=14∣X=13)\\
&=10*0.5372 + 12*0.3824 + 14*0.5372\\
&=17.4815
\end{align*}